# Does it sound natural?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrases

> Some were made to cry. Others, to make others cry

Does it sound natural? If not, how would you write it? I feel like there is something wrong with it, it's a literal traslation from my mother tongue (spanish).  I'm writing and illustrating a comic and this quote is quite important to the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds correct to me. The only shortcoming is that the word "others" refers to two different groups of people in close succession.  If this is an important phrase, rewriting it more clearly is not a bad idea.

Maybe something like

> Some were made to cry, others to cause crying.

or, since this sounds a little formal,

> Some were made to shed tears, others to cause tears to be shed.

You can subsitute your favorite synonym for crying (weeping, lamenting) if you want.

> Some were made for lamenting, others to cause lamentation

I don't know the nature of your comic so I can't guess how formal/lofty/poetic you want it to sound.